# service start automatically on debian 10

Tags: debian, systemd, process, unbound

I have server with `debian 10`, previously on this server `unbound service` installed.
Today I noticed that the service is reset every minute.
I even deleted the file `/lib/systemd/system/unbound.service` and killed process manually
But again it runs automatically; I can not understand what process runs this service twice.
I have two problem:

`#1`: how service start again automatically?

`‍#2`: if service started, why reset again?

also I do not think the reset is due to the service itself.

```
    unbound.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/unbound; generated)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-05-01 14:57:25 +0430; 50s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 24965 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/unbound start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 24985 (unbound)
    Tasks: 8 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 14.3M
   CGroup: /system.slice/unbound.service
                 24985 /usr/sbin/unbound

May 01 14:57:24 INF-dns-ntp02 systemd[1]: Starting unbound.service...
May 01 14:57:24 INF-dns-ntp02 unbound-anchor[24980]: /var/lib/unbound/root.key has content
May 01 14:57:24 INF-dns-ntp02 unbound-anchor[24980]: success: the anchor is ok
May 01 14:57:25 INF-dns-ntp02 unbound[24965]: Starting DNS server: unbound.
May 01 14:57:25 INF-dns-ntp02 systemd[1]: Started unbound.service.
```

**UPDATE**:list files

```
/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.unbound
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.unbound
/etc/init.d/unbound
/etc/insserv.conf.d/unbound
/etc/resolvconf/update.d/unbound
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/unbound.service -> /lib/systemd/system/unbound.service
/etc/systemd/system/unbound.service.d
/etc/systemd/system/unbound.service.wants
/etc/systemd/system/unbound.service.wants/unbound-resolvconf.service -> /lib/systemd/system/unbound-resolvconf.service
/etc/unbound
/etc/unbound/unbound.conf
/etc/unbound/unbound.conf.bk
/etc/unbound/unbound.conf.d
/run/systemd/generator.late/graphical.target.wants/unbound.service -> ../unbound.service
/run/systemd/generator.late/multi-user.target.wants/unbound.service -> ../unbound.service
/run/systemd/generator.late/unbound.service
/run/systemd/units/invocation:unbound.service -> ff49954ca79b45bf851f4f6c9eb007da
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunbound.so.8 -> libunbound.so.8.1.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunbound.so.8.1.0
/usr/sbin/unbound
/usr/sbin/unbound-anchor
/usr/sbin/unbound-checkconf
/usr/sbin/unbound-control
/usr/sbin/unbound-control-setup
/usr/share/doc/libunbound8
/usr/share/doc/unbound
/usr/share/doc/unbound-anchor
```

**Update2:**
remove all `/etc/rc*/[ks]unbound`

```
 unbound.service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/unbound; generated)
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2022-05-01 18:22:25 +0430; 5s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 4854 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/unbound start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4873 (unbound)
    Tasks: 8 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 13.6M
   CGroup: /system.slice/unbound.service
                 4873 /usr/sbin/unbound

May 01 18:22:24 INF-dns-ntp02 systemd[1]: Starting unbound.service...
May 01 18:22:25 INF-dns-ntp02 unbound-anchor[4868]: /var/lib/unbound/root.key has content
May 01 18:22:25 INF-dns-ntp02 unbound-anchor[4868]: success: the anchor is ok
May 01 18:22:25 INF-dns-ntp02 unbound[4854]: Starting DNS server: unbound.
May 01 18:22:25 INF-dns-ntp02 systemd[1]: Started unbound.service.
```

kill Main PID: 4873 exec `kill -9 4873`
but unbound service starts again automatically ...

**Update3:** `grep -r unbound /etc`

```
output: 

/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.unbound:/usr/sbin/unbound flags=(attach_disconnected) {
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.unbound:  /etc/unbound/** r,
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.unbound:  owner /etc/unbound/*.key* rw,
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.unbound:  audit deny /etc/unbound/unbound_control.{key,pem} rw,
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.unbound:  audit deny /etc/unbound/unbound_server.key w,
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.unbound:  /var/lib/unbound/** r,
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.unbound:  owner /var/lib/unbound/** rw,
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.unbound:  audit deny /var/lib/unbound/**/unbound_control.{key,pem} rw,
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.unbound:  audit deny /var/lib/unbound/**/unbound_server.key w,
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.unbound:  /usr/sbin/unbound mr,
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.unbound:  /{,var/}run/{unbound/,}unbound.pid rw,
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.unbound:  /{,var/}run/unbound.ctl rw,
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.unbound:  #include <local/usr.sbin.unbound>
```

Answer (score 0):

A service can be started in several ways. They are shown when you run the command

```
sudo systemctl status servicname
```

under the heading 'TriggeredBy'.

These can all be stopped, started, enabled, disabled, masked and unmasked individually.

An example of another service:

```
    sudo systemctl status libvirtd.service
● libvirtd.service - Virtualization daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/libvirtd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2022-04-28 17:26:32 CEST; 2 days ago
TriggeredBy: ● libvirtd-ro.socket
             ● libvirtd-admin.socket
             ● libvirtd.socket
       Docs: man:libvirtd(8)
```

Comment: I delete `systemd file (/lib/systemd/system/unbound.service)`, but `systemctl status unbound` show me result, and `TriggeredBy` not show for me!

Comment: Removing '*.service' (or '*.socket') files by hand is not recommended. 'systemctl <command> service' manages that for you perfectly. If you do a 'sudo find / -name "*unbound*" | xargs ls -ld ' you got a good chance of finding all references.

Comment: make that "quote star unbound star quote".

    "\*unbound\*"

Comment: I have a lot of files and I can understand which file can stop service! I updated and add list file

Comment: sudo systemctl stop unbound ; sudo systemctl disable unbound ; sudo systemctl mask unbound ; sudo ps -ef | grep -v grep | grep unbound; If the last command shows nothing it is stopped. If not: sudo /etc/init.d/unbound stop ; If that doesn't do it : kill <unbound's-process-id>

Comment: I have done all this before, I stop the service in any way; It starts again automatically

Comment: Are there any

      /etc/rc?.d/S*unbound

links?

Comment: ```
/etc/rc0.d/K01unbound -> ../init.d/unbound
/etc/rc1.d/K01unbound -> ../init.d/unbound
/etc/rc2.d/S01unbound -> ../init.d/unbound
/etc/rc3.d/S01unbound -> ../init.d/unbound
/etc/rc4.d/S01unbound -> ../init.d/unbound
etc/rc5.d/S01unbound -> ../init.d/unbound
/etc/rc6.d/K01unbound -> ../init.d/unbound
```

Comment: Wait. You did it by hand. Did you do a 'sudo systemctl daemon-reload' ?

Comment: yes, 100 times :)

Comment: remove those [SK]*unbound links. Those start it too.

Comment: update-rc.d if I'm right.

Comment: I did and I update the topic for the last result ...

Comment: Assuming you do a full reboot in between. Btw, 'kill -9' is _bad_. Use a plain 'kill <pid>'. Ok, going into weirdo stuff. Check whether you have an /etc/inittab. Should definitely not contain any unbound stuff. Big gun: 'sudo grep -r unbound /etc'.

Comment: updated with output this command  grep -r unbound /etc

Comment: That's no result either. Very rude: rename the unbound executable with 'mv unbound unbound.disabled', reboot and check who's complaining with 'journalctl -b -a'.